# Getstream for mobile apps

Tags: getstream-io

I apologize for the question but I don't have the resources to figure it out myself.
I'm looking for features my next iOS / android app should have and as you can imagine, I'm interested on a "pinch of social" that's why getsream seems to be my saver.
After reading the getting started section and the documentation, I found this warning http://getstream.io/docs/#mobile that confuses me.
I supposed getstream is a managed service that takes care of everything letting me use the REST API to build my mobile community within their phones.
Could you please tell me where I'm wrong?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main reasons we do not recommend integrating Getstream client side (i.e. in the browser or on mobile). First, it is hard to guarantee security when you integrate from the client-side, you have to somehow provision tokens for each user's feed (and feeds they want to target with activities http://getstream.io/docs/#targetting), you could also generate an application wide (read/write) token and ship this to all clients but this is also a bad idea for obvious reasons. Second, we do not recommend using Getstream to store all your activity data, you store references to objects in your local database and enrich the activities from getstream at read time (have a look at our integration libraries for Django/Rails).